# Why MERN app can't communicate with backend if deployed with docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, deployment, proxy, digital-ocean

I deployed a MERN app to a digital ocean droplet with Docker. If I run my *docker-compose.yml* file local on my PC it works well. I have 2 containers: 1  backend, 1  frontend. If I try to compose-up on droplet, it seems the frontend is ok but can't communicate with backend.

[image]

I use *http-proxy-middleware*, my *setupProxy.js* file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://0.0.0.0:5001',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

**I tried** `target: 'http://main-be:5001',` **too, as *main-be* is the name of my backend container, but get the same error.** Just the Request URL is `http://main-be:5001/api/auth/login` in the *chrome/devops/network*.

[image]

...also another page:
[image]

My *docker-compose.yml* file:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  main:

services:
  main-be:
    image: main-be:latest
    container_name: main-be
    ports:
      - '5001:5001'
    networks:
      main:
    volumes:
      - ./backend/config.env:/app/config.env
    command: 'npm run prod'
  main-fe:
    image: main-fe:latest
    container_name: main-fe
    networks:
      main:
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/.env:/app/.env
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    command: 'npm start'
```

My *Dockerfile* in the *frontend* folder:

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My *Dockerfile* in the *backend* folder:

```
FROM node:12-alpine3.14
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci --production
CMD ["npm", "run", "prod"]
```

*backend/package.json* file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch --exec node --experimental-modules server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "prod": "node server.js"
  },
```

*frontend/.env* file:

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
HOST=0.0.0.0
```

*backend/config.env* file:

```
DE_ENV=development
PORT=5001
```

My *deploy.sh* script to build images, copy to droplet...

```
#build and save backend and frontend images
docker build -t main-be ./backend & docker build -t main-fe ./frontend
docker save -o ./main-be.tar main-be & docker save -o ./main-fe.tar main-fe

#deploy services
ssh root@46.111.119.161 "pwd && mkdir -p ~/apps/first && cd ~/apps/first && ls -al && echo 'im in' && rm main-be.tar && rm main-fe.tar &> /dev/null" 

#::scp file
#scp ./frontend/.env root@46.111.119.161:~/apps/first/frontend

#upload main-be.tar and main-fe.tar to VM via ssh
scp ./main-be.tar ./main-fe.tar root@46.111.119.161:~/apps/thesis/

scp ./docker-compose.yml root@46.111.119.161:~/apps/first/
ssh root@46.111.119.161 "cd ~/apps/first && ls -1 *.tar | xargs --no-run-if-empty -L 1 docker load -i"

ssh root@46.111.119.161 "cd ~/apps/first && sudo docker-compose up"
```

*frontend/src/utils/axios.js*:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const baseURL = 'http://localhost:5001';

export default axios.create({ baseURL });
```

*frontend/src/utils/constants.js*:

```
const API_BASE_ORIGIN = `http://localhost:5001`;

export { API_BASE_ORIGIN };
```

I have been trying for days but can't see where the problem is so any help highly appreciated.

Comment: In the proxy setup you do in fact need the Compose service name `main-be` as the host name, not the meaningless 0.0.0.0 ("all interfaces").  But the browser screenshots you show have mentions of `localhost` in them, and that should almost definitely be your DO droplet's DNS name or IP address, not your local machine.  That seems like an application configuration problem and nothing around Docker _per se_.

Comment: Thanks! Found two files in inside frontend\src\utils folder for baseURL. Maybe I should change them to http://main-be:5001/ but not sure. Just added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on MERN (we mainly run Angular & .Net), but I have to warn you of one thing. We had an issue when setting this up in the beginning as well worked locally in containers but not on our deployment servers because we forgot the basic thing about web applications.

Applications run in your browser, whereas if you deploy an application stack somewhere else, the REST of the services (APIs, DB and such) do not. So referencing your IP/DNS/localhost inside your application won't work, because there is nothing there. A container that contains a WEB application is there to only serve your browser (client) files and then the JS and the logic are executed inside your browser, not the container.

I suspect this might be affecting your ability to connect to the backend.

To solve this you have two options.

- Create an HTTP proxy as an additional service and your FE calls that proxy (set up a domain and routing), for instance, Nginx, Traefik, ... and that proxy then can reference your backend with the service name, since it does live in the same environment than API.
- Expose the HTTP port directly from the container and then your FE can call remoteServerIP:exposedPort and you will connect directly to the container's interface. (NOTE: I do not recommend this way for real use, only for testing direct connectivity without any proxy)

Comment: Thanks! I also have axios.js and constants.js files inside frontend\src\utils folder for baseURL. Is there any way I should change this - but for what? Just added the code to the question.

Comment: Yes, i think you should change from http://localhost:5001 to http://46.111.119.161:5001, if the IP is the ip of the given remote server (to which you are trying to access).

In that way you will be directly communicating to the backend.

Comment: Ty! It works with 46.111.119.161:5001! Now I can login into the app, unfortunately if I try to login with bad credentials then I can't recieve the error message as browser says there is an uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data' ) at userActions.js.....It's quite interesting because with localhost:5001 it worked without any problem!