# Docker compose connect back and frontend

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, localhost

Problem: connect my backend and frontend together using Docker compose (Nestjs and Nextjs). Need it to use a unic cluster at AWS. Locally don't work the same way too...

But all worked in separated docker compose (creating a backend at AWS online and locally using my frontend at the created endpoints), but together... I don't have any idea how to solve it. I have try multiples solutions that found on the internet.

connect using docker host on front end:

```
const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res)=>res.json())
  useSWR('http://host.docker.internal:3000/grandetabela', fetcher, {
    onSuccess:(data,key,config)=>{
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
```

This resulte on error: `GET http://host.docker.internal:3000/grandetabela net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` or if i  try local host it's go to a CORS issue.

Inside api in nextjs too, but i don't get the CORS issue:

```
//
try {
    const data = await axios.get('http://host.docker.internal:3000/grandetabela') 
    .then((resp:any)=>{
        return resp
        })
    res.status(200).json(data)
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(502).json({error:'error on sever request'})
}
```

If a try use the localhost as option its cause another problem about AxiosError: Request failed and if i try using another  api from internet i can get response normaly.

to have some ideia what i try look my docker compose... i've try to use the ips... I can ping inside docker but i don't know get acess host:3000 for exemple to consult my endpoints.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    # restart: always
    container_name: 'pgsql'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: pgadmin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpalavra
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
    # networks:
    #   mynetwork:
    #     ipv4_address: 172.20.20.1
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    # restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    # networks:
    #   mynetwork:
    #     ipv4_address: 172.20.70.1

  node-ytalo-backend:
    image: ytalojacs/nestjsbasic_1-0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: >
      sh -c "npm run build \
              npm run start:prod"
    environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: pgadmin
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpalavra
          POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
          POSTGRES_HOST: db
    # networks:
    #   mynetwork:
    #     ipv4_address: 172.20.50.1
  prophet:
    image: ytalojacs/prophetforecast-1_0
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    # networks:
    #   mynetwork:
    #     ipv4_address: 172.20.100.1
  front-end:
    depends_on:
      - node-ytalo-backend
    image: ytalojacs/frontendjsprophet
    environment:
      PORT: 3010
    command: >
      sh -c "npm run build \
              npm run start"
    ports:
      - "3010:3010"
    links: 
      - "node-ytalo-backend:myback.org"
    # networks:
    #   mynetwork:
    #     ipv4_address: 172.20.128.1
# networks:
#   mynetwork:
#     ipam:
#       config:
#         - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

When I use host.docker.internal whith 'curl' inside the docker (docker exec bash) all work as intented too. I can get response from my backend...

Is there something I missed? .env?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why MERN app can't communicate with backend if deployed with docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952390/why-mern-app-cant-communicate-with-backend-if-deployed-with-docker)

Answer (score 1):

You have a similar/same issue to the few I forwarded the same [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952390/why-mern-app-cant-communicate-with-backend-if-deployed-with-docker/71959001#71959001) to.

But I quote here:

> I am no expert on MERN (we mainly run Angular & .Net), but I have to warn you of one thing. We had an issue when setting this up in the beginning as well as worked locally in containers but not on our deployment servers because we forgot the basic thing about web applications.

> Applications run in your browser, whereas if you deploy an application stack somewhere else, the REST of the services (APIs, DB and such) do not. So referencing your IP/DNS/localhost inside your application won't work, because there is nothing there. A container that contains a WEB application is there to only serve your browser (client) files and then the JS and the logic are executed inside your browser, not the container.

> I suspect this might be affecting your ability to connect to the backend.

> To solve this you have two options.
>
> - Create an HTTP proxy as an additional service and your FE calls that proxy (set up a domain and routing), for instance, Nginx, Traefik, ... and that proxy then can reference your backend with the service name, since it does live in the same environment than API.
> - Expose the HTTP port directly from the container and then your FE can call remoteServerIP:exposedPort and you will connect directly to the container's interface. (NOTE: I do not recommend this way for real use, only for testing direct connectivity without any proxy)

## UPDATE 2022-10-05

Added the nginx config from the utility server on how to get request calls from the nginx running inside the container to the other containers on the same network.

Nginx config:

```
server_tokens off;

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

upstream local-docker-verdaccio {
        server verdaccio:4873; #verdaccio is docker compose's service name and port 4873 is port on which container is listening internally
}
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# si.company.verdaccio
server {

        listen 443 http2 ssl;

        server_name verdaccio.company.org;

        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        ssl_certificate /etc/tls/si.company.verdaccio-chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/tls/si.company.verdaccio-unencrypted.key;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://local-docker-verdaccio/;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}

server {

        listen 80;

        server_name verdaccio.company.org;
        return 301 https://verdaccio.company.org$request_uri;
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And corresponding docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - 5fb31181-8e07-4304-9276-9da8c3a581c9:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - /etc/tls/:/etc/tls:ro
  verdaccio:
    container_name: verdaccio
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    expose:
      - "4873"
    image: verdaccio/verdaccio:4
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - d820f373-d868-40ec-bb6b-08a99efddc06:/verdaccio
      - 542b4ca1-aefe-43a8-8fb3-804b46049bab:/verdaccio/conf
      - ab018ca9-38b8-4dad-bbe5-bd8c41edff77:/verdaccio/storage
volumes:
  542b4ca1-aefe-43a8-8fb3-804b46049bab:
    external: true
  5fb31181-8e07-4304-9276-9da8c3a581c9:
    external: true
  ab018ca9-38b8-4dad-bbe5-bd8c41edff77:
    external: true
  d820f373-d868-40ec-bb6b-08a99efddc06:
    external: true
```

Comment: Well... for now this help to find a partial solution. I had a lot of trouble time with nginx... using it and configure (need to delete all the docker configuration from "/etc/nginx/conf.d/* " before make some changes). But if I disable CORS using nginx I can get the endpoint from local host prox.

Comment: another part... the axios ... i don't have the same luck... Get a error 'Internal Server Error' that I can't find a solution.

Comment: For nginx config server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.example.com;

  location /grandetabela/ {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
     proxy_busy_buffers_size   512k;
     proxy_buffers   4 512k;
     proxy_buffer_size   256k;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000/grandetabela/;
    
  }
}             But I can't use it to production, only for test... security... i beleve.

Comment: ah.. the useSWR is working. As I said this this is a partial solution.

Comment: Yes that is true, or you use Nginx, but inside docker env where you need to adjust DNS to the new IP on every service redeploy you can use jwilder proxy (https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) which is a dynamic IP location based on headers inside docker based on docker events. Or you could use Traefik, which will also dynamically adjust the routing rules on docker events aswell.

Comment: We are using Nginx only for SSL termination then, main configuration inside swarm environment goes with Traefik.

But I can send you that part of Nginx if you think it would be helpful to you.

Comment: @matic123 If you could I will be grateful. I'll look into the other possibilities as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have found an actual config on our utility server, but because it is too long ill adjust the answer with it.